# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I've got an error that says:

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected. CommentController is the controller for the comments table.

The `store()` function executes to fill the row in the comment table and one of the important parameter is the post id towards which the comment is made.
posts is a separate table and the id of a post is used to link all its comment in the comments table.

**store() in CommentController**

```
 /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $this->validate($request, [
            'comment' => 'required',
            'v_email' => 'required'
          ]);
          $comment = new Comment;
          $comment->comment_body = $request->input('comment');
          $comment->viewer_email = $request->input('v_email');
          $comment->post_id = $post->id;
          $comment->save();
          return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'commented');
    }
```

**route in web.php** *(I am using route::resource to redirect every url starting with comment to CommentController)*

```
Route::resource('comment', CommentController::class);
```

**form in blade**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' =>['App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@store', $posts->id] , 'method'=>'POST']) !!}

        
        <div class="form-group">
          {{Form::label('comment', 'Comment')}}
          {{Form::textarea('comment','',['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Tell us what you think...'])}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          {{Form::label('v_email', 'Email')}}
          {{Form::text('v_email','',['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Please enter your email. It will be just between us'])}}
        </div>
        {{Form::submit('Send',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: I am passing both request and id still it says 1 argument passed.

Comment: can you explain? why the $posts->id is not visible to store() function? Thanks. @RiggsFolly

Comment: the store function shouldnt get $id parameter, just the request

Comment: how to get the id of the post then?

Comment: @dazed-and-confused post id is not a form input parameter.

Comment: @GiacomoM is right, store function just the request

Answer (score 4):

If you wanna pass the post `$id` to `Controller`, you don't have to use `Route::resource`.
You have to create your own route.

```
Route::post('comment/{id}', CommentController@store)->name('comments.store');
```

Or, if you wanna follow the rest practice, something like:

```
Route::post('posts/{id}/comments', CommentController@store)->name('comments.store');
```

Comment: but why? isn't route::resource the generic routing to a particular controller? I saw your above method of routing in plenty of answers to this similar problem and I am curious why I can't do it with resource?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: yes I read the documentation and it says for POST method route will be directed to store() function. Where is the conflict then? My form also submits via POST method.

Comment: you are inserted a record in a master-detail relationships, not in a normal model. In this way you need to pass a value to store function, so you can not use Route::resource

Comment: If we want to follow the Rest practice, shouldn't the route to be something like, `posts/{id}/comments`

Comment: @Ebi probably you write

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behaviour. The IoC container will only pass the incoming request to the `store` method. So, as only one argument is passed to the method signature, the error will be raised.

In my idea, you have to place the id attribute inside your request body and catch it inside your controller using :
`request->get("id")`